# The same Native query return different results when deployed in another Glassfish server

Tags: oracle, glassfish-4.1, regexp-like

I have a web application that list some data. If I run in local (glasssfish 4.1 jdk 1.8 build 13) it returns me 11 rows. The same happens if I run the query direct on the database (11 rows). But after deploying the app on another glassfish server (glassfish 4.1 jdk 1.8 build 13) it seems it doesn't pay attention to this statement of the query which is in the where clause:

> NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COM.NUMEROCOMUNICADO,'[a-z]')

Because if I run the same native query without that line directly on the database it returns the same rows (30) as in the application deployed in the new glassfish server (30 rows instead of 11). I have checked pools, JNDIs, redeploy, etc but I have no clue what could be happening.

Is that possible? That only a part of the query is being ignored? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well I really don't get to the core of the issue but I have changed my line to this:

> and COM.NUMEROCOMUNICADO NOT LIKE ('%/%')

and it worked.